# Set the Default value in Textview when it is empty

Tags: java, android, android-studio, textview

I'm using AlertDialog Box to request username for my chat application with below code

```
 private void request_user_name() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Enter name:");

    final EditText input_field = new EditText(this);

    builder.setView(input_field);
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
              name = input_field.getText().toString();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
            request_user_name();
        }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

and I call the below code to pass the user_name string to another activity

`intent.putExtra("user_name",name);`

But when it is empty, the app crashes.

How do I set the default value if the textfield is empty and pass the default username to next activity when none is present.

Something like

```
if ( name == null ) {
    // if Textfield is empty set the username anonymous as default
}
else {
    //username from the alertdialog box  
}
```

The log cat of error is 
[log Cat error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLtfn.jpg)

and the line 51 has below code

```
user_name = getIntent().getExtras().get("user_name").toString();
```

Sorry for my code, I'm very much in beginner phase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the name will not be null. It is due to input_field.getText().toString() will return empty string if there are no text in input_field.

Comment: can you update your question  the error log?

Comment: @Sagar I have added error log.

Comment: @TruongGiangDam what if I didn't place the request_user_name(); on oncreate view but instead placed in menu such that when app is opened then it will skip the user_name part and How can I set the default user_name here unless user wish to change user_name they can go to menu and can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
          name = input_field.getText().toString().trim();

          if(name.isEmpty()){
             name = default_name;
          }

          ...

          intent.putExtra("user_name", name);

          ... 
    }
});
```

Edit: Try getting data using this

```
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();       
if(bundle != null){
    String name = bundle.getString("user_name");      
}
```

Comment: @Android_K_Doe, it didn't help the app still crashes when I don't enter any name.

Comment: Please check I have added log cat erro and line where it occured.

Comment: now I realize the problem was different...I have inflated the toolbar menu with option to change username. So I wanted to show the alert Dialog box if they have not set username but if they have then skip the alert Dialog box and only if they needed to change usernmae then from toolbar menu they can launch the alert Dialog box to change the name on click.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling if ( name == null ) {}
directly please use below crash to avoid crash -

```
if(getIntent()!=null)
  {
 if(getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name")!=null)
 {
    String rcvdData=getIntent().getStringExtra("user_name");
   }
  }
```

Comment: priyanka,  what is default user_name value  here if name is null??

Comment: Hirthik , It will be null so you can add your code in it's else block . you can set default value here .

Comment: I used every method but none of it worked and always crashed the app so I am looking for a different approach to solve the probem...here I have created another topic of same probelm but different approach....can you have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49863177/call-a-function-when-an-conditon-is-meet-and-if-not-cancel-the-request